# How to get the Color Name String of Color in c# windows application

Tags: c#, windows, colors

I'm working on some color shades for that I have created some custom properties of colors like this..

```
public struct StaticColors
    {
        //White Shades
        public static Color White = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ecf0f1");
        public static Color White_1 = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#c5d1d4");
        public static Color White_2 = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#a8babf");

        //Red Shades
        public static Color Red = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#db2828");
        public static Color Red_1 = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#a41b1b");
        public static Color Red_2 = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#781414");
    }
```

Now I want the string of any color...

```
var ColorName = StaticColors.White.ToString()
```

then I need "White" in ColorName varibale so I can concatenate with others but I'm getting a string form of RGBA values.

any one can help me please to convert Color into string?

Comment: You'll have to write your own method to turn a Color into a string, because there's no built-in code that could possibly know that you'd want to call a colour with value `a8babf` "White_2".

Comment: I just need To Convert Color into string like //public static Color White ---- then I need that Color datatype in string datatype with same property name. But don't know how to do it.

Comment: You're getting the `ToString` implementation of the `Color` class when you do that. If you want to get the field name of your `StaticColors` class, you would need to use reflection. Alternatively, you could wrap `Color` in your own custom class that has a `"Name"` property and a `"Color"` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) expression, which returns the string name of the member:

```
 var ColorName = nameof(StaticColors.White);
```

---

Another way to accomplish this, if you want `Name` to be a property of the field, is to wrap the `Color` class in your own custom struct and give it a `Name` property:

```
public struct StaticColor
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public Color Color { get; }

    public StaticColor(string name, Color color)
    {
        Name = name;
        Color = color;
    }
}
```

Then in your `StaticColors` struct, you can have fields of this type instead of `Color`:

```
public struct StaticColors
{
    //White Shades
    public static StaticColor White = 
        new StaticColor("White", ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ecf0f1"));
    public static StaticColor White_1 = 
        new StaticColor("White_1", ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#c5d1d4"));
    public static StaticColor White_2 = 
        new StaticColor("White_2", ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#a8babf"));

    //Red Shades
    public static StaticColor Red = 
        new StaticColor("Red", ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#db2828"));
    public static StaticColor Red_1 = 
        new StaticColor("Red_1", ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#a41b1b"));
    public static StaticColor Red_2 = 
        new StaticColor("Red_2", ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#781414"));
}
```

And now you can access the `Color` or the `Name` of any of the properties:

```
var colorName = StaticColors.White.Name;
var colorColor = StaticColors.White.Color;
```

Comment: This is not what I was looking for, but your alternate solution does the great job! Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Oh, I figured out another way - just use the `nameof` expression! I updated my answer (at the top) with how to do it.